# Does the phrase "hang upside down" have a symbolic meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The point is, I'm trying to understand the meaning of the song entitled "Just Like You" by Chromatics. 
And here is the except where the above-mentioned phrase is used:
(the full lyrics if needed: 
https://genius.com/Chromatics-just-like-you-lyrics)

"He looks just like you
He even says the same things
He's always hanging upside down..."

So.. it doesn't seem to have a literal meaning. Maybe it means "messing around/behaving like a child", or maybe that persons sees the world differently, in their distorted way.
It is probably important to know the story of the song to get its meaning, but I've failed to find any information.

I would be really grateful if you helped. 
Till then, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image that immediately comes to mind is of a vampire. The lyrics are pretty cryptic, so I can't tell whether that's what they're referring to. The mythology of the vampire is interwoven with imagery of fallen angels, who are also sometimes depicted as hanging upside down. The lyrics do have some references that might indicate that ("Back in paradise," "He says he's going underground"). But it's all pretty vague.